# Embed web app in mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, webview, android-webview

I want to develop a web app that will work in a server. Using apache or gunicorn, or something similar.

Now I need to know if there is any way to make a "native app" that will redirect to the web app.

Basically the native app redirect to the responsive web site that will run inside a webview. The native app only is needed to provide a a shortcut to the web app in the smartphone and also add the option of install in apple/android store.

This is possible? I can develop this "native app" with phonegap, but I need to embed the responsive web app powered by apache/nginx/gunicorn.

Any insights about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is what people doing on my office :

1. They created a responsive web.
2. They created a native app (**not** hybrid), in other word : they use eclipse/xcode
3. The native app basically is just a full screen `WebView`

With this, they successfully employ android & iOS native apps only with `WebView` and upload it to their respective store.

Comment: @user2990084 Unfortunately, i dont understand about apple. You may want to create a new question to ask specifically about apple's policy :). However, the GP is okay for this kind of apps.